# PostgreSQL 12 Server Remote Setup Questions

Tags: postgresql, installation, remote-access, remote-server

I have successfully built PostgreSQL 12 from source on Linux Mint and it runs just fine. I created a database locally using the command line and I also created a database remotely from Windows 10 using the command line. The Linux machine is using a static IP and it is working fine too and I am able to SSH into it from other computers in the network and even outside the house.

So, my question is, how do I get my Windows 10 machines to connect to the Linux database server by either pgAdmin or some other client? When I run pgAdmin from my Windows 10 machine and try to connect to the server with just the basic information, no setting of the SSL settings or SSH Tunneling, I get the following error:

```
unable to connect to server: 

could not connect to server: Connection refused (Ox000027 40/1 0061) Is the server running on host 
"96.33.242.182" and accepting 
TCP/IP connections on port 5432'
```

If I try to connect where I turn on SSL compression and setup the settings for SSH Tunneling, I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to server: 

server closed the connection unexpectedly 
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

I would like to be able to connect to my Linux PostgreSQL server from all Windows 10 machines as well as from a client on my Android phone while away from home. That is my goals at the moment. One last question, do I need to install PostgreSQL on my client machines in order to connect to the server and use it? At this moment I am just testing with the one Windows 10 machine and I do have PostgreSQL 12 installed on it. I have tried searching the Internet to find the answers myself, but I have come up empty.

Comment: You should check the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: I have already setup hba_config & postgresql.config as the directions I found in my search. I have tried all suggestions on the online tutorials.

Comment: You should check the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: You already said that and I left a comment to it.

Comment: Well, what did you find in the log file?